# драйвер для базы оракл?

Tags: java, oracle

Использовал mysql драйвер для соединения с базой.
db.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Требуется перейти на оракл, какой драйвер для соединения с базой нужно использовать?

окружение - база оракл, spring5, java8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Скачайте драйвер
2. Установите его в локальный мавен репозиторий
3. Укажите класс в application.properties

[Пример](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/)